# Проблема с командой "предложение к разработчику" в боте

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Я решил создать команду "!change_add" в своём боте, чтобы пользователи могли писать !change_add abc и чтобы некое предложение ABC записывалось в .txt файл. Короче если кто-то хочет чтобы я добавил что-либо в бота, это предложение записывалось ко мне. С записью в .txt файл я разобрался, вот только я не могу понять как сформулировать команду чтобы текст после !change_add записывался в переменную. Сначала я узнал что это легко можно сделать через метод removeprefix(). Но вот незадача - он добавляется только в Python 3.9. А Python 3.9 требует установленной OS Windows 8 и выше. Но у меня Windows 7. Короче если кто знает как это можно сделать без использования removeprefix(), отпишитесь.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. removeprefix(), судя по названию, совершенно не связана с записью текста в переменную. Вам нужно взять текст после слов !change_add? Для этого есть дюжина способов в любой версии питона.

Comment: Еммм, зачем такой велосипед с записами в файл, почему просто не отправлять предложения вам в ЛС?

Comment: Просто это удобнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [код функции](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/#specification) `removeprefix()`:

```
def removeprefix(self, prefix):
    if self.startswith(prefix):
        return self[len(prefix):]
    else:
        return self[:]
```

Можете назвать любым именем и использовать в любой версии питона.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.